# Como hacer que mi pagina trabaje de forma responsiva con primeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

estoy trabajando con angular y primeNG , el problema que tengo es la parte de responsive. Leyendo la documentación no tiene mucha dificultad es solo agregar las etiquetas y seria , igual no tengo mucha experiencia en diseño y css por eso ahora estoy solo a prueba y error, no se si me faltara algo o los estilos se están pisando en algún lado. les adjunto las imágenes de la tabla como se ve la versión móvil se ve horrible. por lo que entiendo con la etiqueta de [resonsive] debería funcionar

[image: Tabla]

```css
/* Clase para crear un Margen en el lado derecho.
   Utilizado para dar espacio entre los radiobuttons, inputs, buttons, etc. Creados desde un ngFor
   Añade un leve margen al lado derecho de cada radiobutton, de lo contrario se muestran pegados uno del otro. 
*/
.right-margin {
    margin-right: 15px !important;
}

/* Clase para crear un Margen en la parte inferior (bottom).
   Utilizado para dar espacio entre los radiobuttons, inputs, buttons, etc. Creados desde un ngFor
   Añade un leve margen en la parte inferior de cada radiobutton, de lo contrario se muestran pegados uno del otro. 
*/
.bottom-margin {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.top-margin {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    .div-p-table {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.div-p-table {
    align-self: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!-- Reportes -->
    <div fxLayout="column" *ngIf="!visualizarFormulario" style="width: 100%;" >
        <div style="align-self: center;">
            <app-precios-flores-ultimas-diez-semanas-table-btn></app-precios-flores-ultimas-diez-semanas-table-btn>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="print-section" class="div-p-table">
            <p-table [value]="listadoResultado | slice:1 " [columns]="columnasGrilla" [customSort]="true" [responsive]="true" 
            [rows]="paginadorConfig.registros" [paginator]="paginadorConfig.paginador" [pageLinks]="paginadorConfig.paginas" [rowsPerPageOptions]="paginadorConfig.registrosPorPaginas" 
            [autoLayout]="true">
                <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                    <div *ngFor="let titulo of titulosGrilla" class="prime-grid-cell-font">
                        {{titulo}}
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                    <tr class="prime-grid-cell-font">
                        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [hidden]="col.hidden">
                            <span innerHTML="{{col.header}}"></span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                    <tr class="prime-grid-cell-font">
                        <td *ngFor="let col of columns"[ngStyle]="{'text-align': behaviorTableService.columnStyle(rowData[col.field])}">
                            <ng-container *ngIf="behaviorTableService.typeColumn(rowData[col.field])" >
                              {{rowData[col.field]}}
                            </ng-container>
                            <ng-container *ngIf="!behaviorTableService.typeColumn(rowData[col.field])">
                                {{rowData[col.field] | number:'1.0-0'}}
                            </ng-container>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
                    <div class="prime-grid-cell-font" *ngFor="let texto of listadoPiePaginaGrilla" style="text-align : left" style="font-weight: normal;">{{texto}}</div>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="grow" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="bottom-margin top-margin">
            <app-precios-flores-ultimas-diez-semanas-table-btn></app-precios-flores-ultimas-diez-semanas-table-btn>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para la versión 11.04.10 de primeNg, lo que hago es al igual que en tu código, poner el atributo `[responsive]="true"` pero para que al reducir el tamaño y visualizarse en modo "stack" aparezcan los nombres de las columnas a la izquierda, éstos deben ir dentro de etiquetas con la clase *p-column-title* (te pongo un extracto de la documentación):

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                <span class="p-column-title">{{col.header}}</span>
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
</ng-template>
```